Response body properties are set to null after calling endpoint using RestTemplate.exhange()
I was getting the response after calling endpoint using RestTemplate.exchange() method. But the response body properties are set to null even passing DTO
ResponseEntity response = RestTemplate.exchange(url,HTTP.GET,entity,DTOClass.class)
Log.info("response: {}",response);
Output:
<200:DTOClass{emp1:null,name:null,salary:null}
No error is throwing. how to resolve this?
